# How to write signal handler for sigabrt signal?

Tags: c++, signals

I am trying to delete an already deleted object and I am getting a SIGABRT signal.
I know this signal aborts my program, but I want to catch this signal in a signal handler and display the message that I am deleting an already deleted object...

Here is the code I have tried, but it doesn't seem to work.
Please help me figure out what's wrong in it?

```
using namespace std;

class myclass
{
public:
   myclass()  { cout <<"myclass constructed\n"; }
   ~myclass() { cout <<"myclass destroyed\n"; }
};

void func(int);

int main (void)
{
  signal(SIGABRT,func);
  myclass * pt;

  pt = new myclass[3];

  delete[] pt;
  delete[] pt;

  return 0;
}

void func(int)
{ 
   signal(SIGABRT,func);
   cout << "trying to delete unallocated memory, exiting....\n";
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? (Works fine here BTW. And please try to format your code a bit.)

Comment: it just aborts without giving me the msg "trying to delete unallocated memory, exiting...."

Comment: I see the message printed fine (g++4.6.1/ubuntu 11 x86) if that is how you define "works".

Comment: what could be the modification if i dont want to abort the program and continue in normal mode...?

Comment: A double deallocation is a bug in the code. Trying to find a way to cope with this is the wrong to way address it. Preventing it is the (only) solution.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/SIG30-CPP.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

Comment: On MacOS X 10.7.2 with G++ 4.6.1, I get what is plausibly the expected output: `myclass constructed /
myclass constructed /
myclass constructed /
myclass destroyed /
myclass destroyed /
myclass destroyed /
myclass destroyed /
myclass destroyed /
myclass destroyed /
x(31507) malloc: *** error for object 0x10d500900: pointer being freed was not allocated /
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug /
trying to delete unallocated memory, exiting....`.  The destructors are executed twice.

Comment: You should not be printing during a signal handler(). The state of the stack is not well defined in terms of the language.

Comment: deleting a pointer may not always give you a sigabrt (technically what happens is undefined). Maybe you need to compile with debugging turned on.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard says (section 7.14, paragraph 4 of both [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> An implementation need not generate any of these signals, except as a result of explicit
>   calls to the raise function.

The C++ standard doesn't give any additional additional guarantees.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html) says:

> The *abort*() function shall cause abnormal process termination to occur, unless the signal SIGABRT is being caught and the signal handler does not return.
>
> The abnormal termination processing shall include the default actions defined for SIGABRT and may include an attempt to effect fclose() on all open streams.
>
> The SIGABRT signal shall be sent to the calling process as if by means of *raise*() with the argument SIGABRT.
>
> The status made available to *wait*() or *waitpid*() by *abort*() shall be that of a process terminated by the SIGABRT signal. The *abort*() function shall override blocking or ignoring the SIGABRT signal.

So, yeah, you have no basis for expecting to see a SIGABRT at all; you're lucky you aren't encountering [nasal demons](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/msg/095466f60ec70e47)!